# TreeView to database or at least DataTable

Tags: database, datatable, treeview

The main question **how to fully traverse/circumvent through all TreeView, for transforming Tree structure into a Table structure** on C#?
I want to note that the TreeView may contain a different number of branches, with different depths and different names.
I found a lot of information how to populate TreeView e.g. from DataTable, but I didn’t found information how to recursively traverse/circumvent a TreeView and populate/fill data e.g. to DataTable.

As sample I have following TreeView:

```
Aaron
-Baldwin
--Caleb
---Dale
--Earl
-Fabian
Gabriel
-Harold
-Ian
```

Necessary to convert the TreeView into e.g. DataTable:

```
+--------------------------+
| id | Name     | ParentId |
+--------------------------+
| 1  | Aaron    | null     |
| 2  | Baldwin  | 1        |
| 3  | Caleb    | 2        |
| 4  | Dale     | 3        |
| 5  | Earl     | 2        |
| 6  | Fabian   | 1        |
| 7  | Gabriel  | null     |
| 8  | Harold   | 7        |
| 9  | Ian      | 7        |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is work well:

```
    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TraverseTreeView(treeView1);
        string temp = String.Empty;
        foreach (string str in name)
            temp += str + Environment.NewLine;
        MessageBox.Show(temp);
        name.Clear();
    }
    List<string> name = new List<string>();
    private void TraverseTreeView(TreeView tview)
    {
        TreeNode temp = new TreeNode();
        for (int k = 0; k < tview.Nodes.Count; k++)
        {
            temp = tview.Nodes[k];
            name.Add(k+"\t"+temp.Text+"\tnull");
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Nodes.Count; i++)
                visitChildNodes(temp.Nodes[i]);
        } 
    }
    private void visitChildNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        name.Add(node.Text);
        for (int j = 0; j < node.Nodes.Count; j++)
            visitChildNodes(node.Nodes[j]);
    }
```

But there is still several things that I don't know how to realize:
1. Do not use global variable (List name) for collecting result;
2. Correctly collect data perhaps in DataTable, in format "1  | Aaron    | null".
Please chech code below, and fix mistaks:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = TraverseTreeView(treeView1);
        string temp = String.Empty;
        foreach (string str in dt)
            temp += str + Environment.NewLine;
        MessageBox.Show(temp);
        dt.Clear();
    }
    //List<string> name = new List<string>();
    private DataTable TraverseTreeView(TreeView tview)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
        TreeNode temp = new TreeNode();
        for (int k = 0; k < tview.Nodes.Count; k++)
        {
            temp = tview.Nodes[k];
            dt.Rows.Add(k, temp.Text, null);
            //name.Add(temp.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Nodes.Counst; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(i, visitChildNodes(temp.Nodes[i]).Text, i - 1);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private DataTable visitChildNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        //name.Add(node.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
        for(int j = 0; j < node.Nodes.Count; j++)
            dt.Rows.Add(j, visitChildNodes(node.Nodes[j]).Text, j - 1);
        return dt;
    }
```